# How to inject nested IOptions with IServiceCollection.Configure

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, configuration

I have a Settings object that contains nested objects. I call WebApplicationBuilder.Configuration.Bind("Settings", options) to bind all the nested settings to the big Settings object, and I call IServiceCollection.Configure to make the big Settings object available through dependency injection. The only thing I don't like about this is that I have to inject the whole big object whenever I want to use it; I'm not able just to inject one of the nested objects. Can someone tell me what would be the best way to set things up so I can inject just one of the nested options objects if I need to?

```
public class Settings
{
    public RepositoryOptions Repository { get; set; } = new();

    public StoredProcedureOptions StoredProcedures { get; set; } = new();

    ...
}
```

Program.cs Main:

```
...
builder.Services.AddBLLServices(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Settings", options);
    options.Repository.IntegrationDatabaseConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Integration") ?? string.Empty;
    options.StoredProcedures.MessageBrokerDatabaseConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MessageBroker") ?? string.Empty;
});
...
```

AddBLLServices method:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddBLLServices(this IServiceCollection services, Action<Settings> configureOptions)
{
    // Make Settings object available through DI
    services.Configure(configureOptions);

    // Add services based on settings
    var options = new Settings();
    configureOptions.Invoke(options);
    Configure(services, options);

    return services;
}
```

Attempting to inject IConfig of a nested object injects an unconfigured object. Because I'm passing an Action to IServiceCollection.Configure I don't know how I could pull out one of the nested objects.

Edit:

Attempting to follow the advice of itsdaniel0 I have changed my AddBLLServices method to this to try to register the nested objects with DI:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddBLLServices(this IServiceCollection services, Action<Settings> configureOptions)
{
    var options = new Settings();
    configureOptions.Invoke(options);

    services.Configure<Settings>(o => o = options);
    services.Configure<RepositoryOptions>(o => o = options.Repository);
    services.Configure<StoredProcedureOptions>(o => o = options.StoredProcedures);
    services.Configure<WireTapListenerOptions>(o =>
    {
        var opt = new Settings();
        configureOptions.Invoke(opt);
        o = opt.WireTapListener;
    });
    services.Configure<WireTapQueueListenerOptions>(o => o = options.WireTapQueueListener);
    services.Configure<ServiceListenerOptions>(o => o = options.ServiceListener);
    services.Configure<EmailAlertOptions>(o => o = options.EmailAlert);

    Configure(services, options);

    return services;
}
```

But when I try to inject the options in a constructor the value is not configured.

Comment: Why don't you split your config out into multiple classes, then register them like that?

E.G.
services.Configure<RepositoryOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Settings:Repository"))

Comment: @itsdaniel0 My AddBLLServices method is in my BLL assembly and I want it to be agnostic of how the assembly that consumes it configures the settings, so I let it pass an action. I suppose I could split it into an extension method for each nested object, but then I lose the convenience of the recursive object binding.

Comment: You're registering the whole object in DI though, so it can only ever resolve the object
You can still keep the action, but do different registrations for each nested class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original problem is because you're registering a single instance of the class, then inject the subclasses. You need to register them each individually.
Usually you would bind each class to a configuration section

```
services.Configure<SubClass>(config.Bind("Parent:Nested"));
```

In the position you're in, there is no built-in way.
I'd suggest the following extension method to register an instance

It's worth pointing out, this won't allow for the use of IOptionsSnapshot, but can be adapted to suit your needs as required

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection Configure<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, TOptions instance)
        where TOptions : class
    {
        if (services is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        _ = services.AddOptions();
        _ = services.AddSingleton<IOptions<TOptions>>(new OptionsWrapper<TOptions>(instance));

        return services;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so `services.Configure(options.EmailAlert);`

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly well.

Can I ask your opinion: Do you think this is bad practice? Should I just inject the big Settings object? Should I split my AddBLLServices method into different methods that each takes one of the nested configuration objects?

Comment: There's not necessarily a right or wrong. It all depends on your use-case. Take a read of the MS Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options